# How to debug and step into a native code project from inside a .NET core C# project?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, .net-core

I am developing a .NET core (.NET Standard 1.6) application in VS2015. The application calls C++ code via P/Invoke. Now I need to **step into** the C/C++ code of my native dll project.

In regular .NET application, by *enabling unmanaged code debugging* in the property window of the application, we can step into the C/C++ code directly:

[image: step into the C/C++ code]

But I can't find such option on a .NET core project. And I know that I can attach the debugger to the application to debug native code *only*, but that's not suitable for my case.

Again, I want to debug from managed C# code **into** native C/C++ code.

Any ideas?

Maybe I should switch back to .NET Framework so I can debug the native code. It's really hard to debug by `printf`. :(

Comment: also voted to close as off topic. read this on what questions can be asked http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Yes, I know. But I'm just asking [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738006/how-do-i-debug-a-native-code-project-from-inside-a-managed-code-project-c-c) except that I'm using .NET Core not .NET Framework. Since that question is not closed as off topic, I won't close mine.

Comment: The gif is used to illustrate the meaning of **step into the C/C++ code directly**.

Comment: This is not (yet?) supported - check the issues like https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10524 or https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/368. If you need VS to spell it for you, then instead of launching, put a pause in your program (e.g. a `Console.ReadKey` call), and then try attaching to the dotnet.exe process selecting "Managed (CoreCLR)" and "Native" code types - you'll get a message box stating explicitly that "Interop debugging is not supported".

Comment: @cynic thanks! That's really disappointing. I will confirm it in VS as you said.

Comment: @cynic Confirmed. I have answered my question following your words. Thanks very much!

Comment: @cynic - Have been trying this with 2022 [.NEt 6.0 + native C via Interop]. Visual Studio crashes every timeit hits an interop boundary..... This all worked when compiled for framework 4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
The mixed mode debugging, i.e. debugging from managed C# code into native C/C++ code, has been implemented. See [Tutorial: Debug managed and native code in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-managed-and-native-code).

**UPDATE**
The feature may have already been implemented, see [this](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/9919).

---

Just as @cynic said, this is not yet supported now (**2016-11-1**).

That can be verified by following steps provided by cynic.

1. Put a pause in your program (e.g. a Console.ReadKey call).
2. Attaching to the dotnet.exe process selecting "Managed (CoreCLR)" and "Native" code types
3. You'll get a message box stating explicitly that "Interop debugging is not supported".

[image: Not supported.]

Here is [a proper way](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10524#issuecomment-238314570) to debug the native dll.

> 1. Right click on the solution, Add Existing Project
> 2. Open 'dotnet.exe'. This is normally installed to 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe'.
> 3. You should now see another node in solution explorer for dotnet.exe. Right click it to bring up project properties:
> 4. Change the working directory to be what you want
> 5. Change the arguments to be the path to your built dll
> 6. Change the exe project to your startup project
>
> RECOMENDED: Go to Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run, uncheck 'Only build startup projects and dependcies on Run'

Comment: Using MS Visual Studio 15.5.7 I am now able to step from managed code (.NET core 2.0)  across into native code when my app is running on Windows. I'd really love to know if this is (or will be) possible for an app running on the Linux side or if this is a lost cause.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I will try if remote debug on linux support this when I'm free.

Comment: I'm currently looking at the instructions here:https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/building/debugging-instructions.md to try to figure out if its possible to do some kind of mixed mode debugging on Linux.